# Exercise 1.1.3 in Charles Weibel’s book “An Introduction to Homological Algebra”

Tags: vector-spaces, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I am trying to teach myself some homological algebra and I got stuck right at the start with Exercise 1.1.3 from the book “An Introduction to Homological Algebra” by Charles Weibel.

**Exercise 1.1.3** (Split exact sequences of vector spaces) Choose vector spaces $\{B_n, H_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ over a field, and set $C_n=B_n\oplus H_n\oplus B_{n-1}$. Show that the projection-inclusions $C_n\to B_{n-1}\subset C_{n-1}$ make $\{C_n\}$ into a chain complex, and that every chain complex of vector spaces is isomorphic to a complex of this form.

**My take so far**

The first part is just a matter of checking that the projection-inclusions $\partial_n\colon C_n\to C_{n-1}$ satisfy $\partial_n\circ\partial_{n+1}=0$, which is obvious since $\partial_n$ basically does the following: $(x,y,z)\mapsto(z,0,0)$ and so when applied twice gives zero.

The second part is trickier for me. I started with a chain complex of vector spaces $$\cdots\to V_{n+1}\stackrel{d_{n+1}}{\to}V_n\stackrel{d_n}{\to}V_{n-1}\to\cdots$$ and looked for a map $$u_n\colon V_n\to \operatorname{im} d_{n+1}\oplus (\ker d_n/\operatorname{im} d_{n+1})\oplus \operatorname{im} d_n$$ as suggested by the notation $\{B_n, H_n\}$ in the text of the exercise.

I have come up with only one reasonable map, defined as follows. Choose a basis $\mathcal{B}_1$ for $\operatorname{im} d_{n+1}$ and extend it first to a basis $\mathcal{B}_1\sqcup\mathcal{B}_2$ for $\ker d_n$, then to a basis $\mathcal{B}_1\sqcup\mathcal{B}_2\sqcup\mathcal{B}_3$ for $V_n$. As a result, each vector $v\in V_n$ can be uniquely written as $v=v_1\oplus v_2\oplus v_3$ where $v_i$ is a linear combination of elements of $\mathcal{B}_i$, $i=1,2,3$. Finally define $$u_n(v)=v_1\oplus [v_2] \oplus d_n(v_3)$$
where $[~]$ denotes the homology class.

I checked and $u_n$ is indeed an isomorphism of vector spaces, but alas it does not seem to commute with the differentials since in general $$(u_{n-1} \circ d_n)(v) = 0 \neq d_n v_3 = (\partial_n\circ u_n)(v)\;.$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just curious (I'm new to homological algebra). How do you prove that $u_n$ is an isomorphism?

Is it enough to look at the s.e.s:
1) $0\rightarrow \text{im}(d_{n+1})\rightarrow \text{ker}(d_n)\rightarrow \frac{\text{ker}(d_n)}{\text{im}(d_{n+1})}\rightarrow 0$


2) $0\rightarrow \text{ker}(d_n)\rightarrow V_n\rightarrow \text{im}(d_n)\rightarrow 0$

Then use that: $\text{ker}(d_n)\cong \text{im}(d_{n+1})\oplus \frac{\text{ker}(d_n)}{\text{im}(d_{n+1})}$ and $V_n\cong\text{ker}(d_n)\oplus\text{im}(d_{n+1})$ to get the isomorphism?

Comment: Thanks for making this post.  Stuck at same spot in Weibel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually everything you wrote is correct, except the last equation!

Why do you say $(u_{n-1} \circ d_n)(v) = 0$? In reality, $d_n v$ is an element of $C_{n-1}$ that you need to write as a sum $v_1' + v_2' + v_3'$ where $v_1' \in \operatorname{im}d_n$ etc. But you know that such a sum is unique, and you already have the decomposition $d_n v = d_n v + 0 + 0$. Therefore $u_{n-1} d_n v = (d_n v, 0, 0)$.

On the other hand, $\partial_n u_n v = (d_n v_3, 0, 0)$. But by the identification that allowed you to define $\partial_n$, namely $C_n / \operatorname{ker} d_n = \operatorname{im} d_n$, it follows that this last element is equal to $(d_n v, 0, 0)$. Everything checks out.

PS: You perhaps know this, but working over a field was essential here. Being able to write stuff as direct sums is what allows you to perform this trick; over a general ring this result is false.

Comment: Thank you, very clear! Indeed I miscalculated $(u_{n-1}\circ d_n)(v)$...